# Calculating magnitude of 3D vector in specific circumstance.

Tags: vectors, 3d

I’m writing a program where there exists points in space and each point is at the exact center of a cube. For each point, I have two angles (vertical and horizontal rotation, or pitch and yaw) as well as the shortest distance from the point to any face on its respective cube.

Vertical rotation is between -90 and 90 degrees, horizontal rotation is between -180 and 180 degrees.

Would anyone happen to know the formula by which I could determine the distance between a point and a remote coordinate within a face (plane) of its cube using those three elements?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You have some collection of cubes, with their centers, and sizes (the distances between the center and the faces gives you that). I don't get what role the angles play, nor do I get what a 'remote coordinate within a face' is supposed to mean.

Comment: The angles give you the direction of the vector, and the remote coordinate is simply a point within a face of the cube. I am trying to calculate the distance between the center of the cube and any point on the surface using only the facing direction of the center point and the known distance from the center point to any face. My apologies.

Comment: This does not clarify anything. What vector? What's the effect of this vector on anything. By point withing a face do you mean a point on the surface of the cube?

Comment: Yes, a point on the surface. Perhaps vector is the wrong term. It’s a line extending outward from the center to the surface.

Comment: What role does this vector play in this problem? And what exactly are you trying to find? The distance between some given point on the surface of a cube and the some point that is at the center of the cube? So what exactly is the issue with this? You just compute $\sqrt{(a-b)\cdot (a-b)}$. Where $a$ is the point on the surface and $b$ is the center point.

Comment: Because you do not know the coordinate location of the point on the surface. You only know which direction the point is facing and the size of the cube.

Comment: So is that vector given by $(\cos\phi\sin\theta, \sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ and you want to find the intersection of the ray defined by this vector and the center of the cube with the cube's faces? If that is your issue then you should just use a standard ray-cube intersection algorithm.

Comment: I could calculate the unit vector in that form, yes. I think you understand now; I am just not familiar with the standard algorithms. I’ll research it as well.

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: Yeah, there's just so many individual examples so I may have trouble finding precisely the circumstance that I am trying to address.

Comment: It's ray-AABB, in case your cube is axis aligned, and ray-OBB if it's not axis-aligned.